# Why does a C array decay to a pointer when passed with size

Tags: c, arrays

I understand why an array decays to a pointer when passed to a function without specifying its size, eg.:

```
void test(int array[]);
```

Why does it do so when passed with the size? eg.

```
void test(int array[3]);
```

I am having trouble with `sizeof` under the latter function signature, which is frustrating as the array length is clearly known at compile time.

Comment: That is just how the language is defined (and has been for a very long time) - either pass the size as a separate parameter, or embed the array in a struct, or switch to a different language.

Comment: Because that's how it was designed. We could give you a history lesson, but it wouldn't help you much.

Comment: It's an optimization on behalf of the language designers. One could certainly agree with them, or consider it premature in retrospect. But that's how the language is designed.

Comment: I really hate the usage of "An array decays to a pointer".  I'd say it's more accurate to say "An array decays to an address."  An array is a region of memory - it exists. It *has* an address - a *valid* address that can't be changed, nor assigned to.  (You can't assign to an *address* - you can assign to the memory the address refers to.)  A pointer, on the other hand, is a *variable* (another memory location) that can *contain* an address, which may or may not be valid.

Comment: I guess my point is, why bother allowing the latter syntax if the compiler is just going to ignore the provided size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void test(int* array);
void test(int array[]);
void test(int array[3]);
```

All these variants are the same. C just lets you use alternative spellings but even the last variant explicitly annotated with an array size decays to a pointer to the first element.

That is, even with the last implementation you could call the function with an array of any size:

```
void test(char str[10]) { }

test("test"); // Works.
test("let's try something longer"); // Still works.
```

There is no magic solution, the most readable way to handle the problem is to either make a `struct` with the array + the size or simply pass the size as an additional parameter to the function.

LE: Please note that this conversion only applies to the first dimension of an array. When passed to a function, an `int[3][3]` gets converted to an `int (*)[3]`, not `int **`.

Comment: So int array[3] is more for the programmer's benefit than anything else?

Comment: In my opinion, it shouldn't be used. It might give the user a false sense of security (“oh, this function only accepts an array of length 3 so I don’t need to check the length myself”)

Answer (score 1):

Because you would not be able to call such a function properly. In almost all contexts an array decays to a pointer to the first element, and at any attempt to call the function an array would first be converted to a pointer and the call would be a mismatch. The only contexts where an array does *not* decay are the operators `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, `_Alignas` and `&`. These are easier to detect syntactically.